# Ng zorro is not working with storybook angular 13

Tags: angular, storybook

I'm tryning to integrate ng zorro with storybook in an angular  library.
We I run storyBook I have this issue for my first component:
core.mjs:14697 NG0304: 'nz-avatar' is not a known element:

1. If 'nz-avatar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nz-avatar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Below my module.ts

````
const components = [
 AvatarComponent
];

const ngZorroModules = [
NzAvatarModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ngZorroModules,
  ],
  declarations: [components],
  exports: [components, ngZorroModules],

})
export class ComponentModule {}```

Do you have any idea about this issue?
````

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Your error is actually related to not doing the imports correctly. So AppModule has to import ComponentModule if you want to use your AvatarComponent in app.component.html.

Walk with me for creating a working module which contains declarations and imports some ng-zorro modules:

1. Follow the instructions here to initialize a new project:
   https://ng.ant.design/docs/getting-started/en
2. Then, create a custom component - take for example the NzDemoAvatarBasicComponent component from the first code sample here:
   https://ng.ant.design/components/avatar/en#ng-content - and place it into a demo.component.ts file
3. Create a demo.module.ts containing the declaration for your component (e.g. NzDemoAvatarBasicComponent) and the imports for NzAvatarModule:

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { NzAvatarModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/avatar';
    import { NzDemoAvatarBasicComponent } from './demo.component';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
          CommonModule, 
          NzAvatarModule
      ],
      declarations: [
          NzDemoAvatarBasicComponent // <-- your custom component here
      ],
      exports: [
          NzDemoAvatarBasicComponent
          // if you want to use nz-avatar directly, then add NzAvatarModule here to the exports array:
          // NzAvatarModule,
          // otherwise there is no need to export it if you use only your custom component which is wrapping nz-avatar. 
      ],
    })
    export class DemoModule {}
```

4. Go to AppModule and make sure you place your module (e.g. DemoModule) in imports.

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { NZ_I18N } from 'ng-zorro-antd/i18n';
    import { en_US } from 'ng-zorro-antd/i18n';
    import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
    import en from '@angular/common/locales/en';
    import { DemoModule } from './demo.module';
    
    registerLocaleData(en);
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        DemoModule, // <----- your custom module here
      ],
      providers: [{ provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: en_US }],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

5. Go to app.component.html, empty it and add your custom component.

```html
<nz-demo-avatar-basic></nz-demo-avatar-basic>
```

Now you should see that sample component being rendered when you serve the app.

========
Original answer:

I notice you are adding NzAvatarModule to the "imports" array in an unusual way, it's wrapped with an extra array.

Comment: I'm using this way of imports because I'll have many ngZorro modules to import. Even when trying your suggestion I'm still having the same error

Comment: I realised now you define a ComponentModule and you don't show what you do with AppModule - could you share your app.module.ts file and your app.component.ts and app.component.html? AppModule has to import ComponentModule. The error seems like you are not importing ComponentModule.

Comment: I have updated the answer with instructions on how to add a custom component and define a module declaring it.

Comment: I have found it. In fact, I forgot to add this in the preview.js
addDecorator(
  moduleMetadata({
    imports: [
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      UiKitModuleModule,
    ]
  }),
);